Hilbert Mumford Criteria for $\mathbb P^1$
Consider the action of $SL_2$ on $\mathbb P^1$. We know that there is no non-constant homogenous invariant polynomial, so vacuously there are no semistable points.
In particular $(1,1)$ is not semistable.
So by Hilbert Mumford Criteria, there should exist a one parameter subgroup $\lambda$ such that the Hilbert Mumford index $\mu((1,1),\lambda) < 0$.

What is explicitly this $\lambda$?

